# iText Limiting Text Size in a Text Field

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Is there any way we can specify the max number of chars a TextField can take in the PDF form created using iText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, the [createTextField](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfFormField.html#createTextField%40com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int%41) method takes a maximum length.

http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfFormField.html#createTextField(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int)

Comment: Sadly, the SO URL parser is broken. I cannot seem to link directly to the method in question, but it's there.